# How to manage laravel session using Auth or middleware

Tags: laravel, session

I am having the issue of maintaining the session in laravel subdomain could anyone help me for this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: I can help you, IFF you explain more and share more info.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Stackoverflow. Please provide more details on what you tried and what exactly is the problem. You can read this for help - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you provide code, which shows how you declare and use laravel session ?